# SQL Query to insert two variables into one column table

Tags: sql, insert

I am having trouble inserting data into my database. I have 3 pdfs I read their data using substrings.

Each pdf it has data about id, brand, size, color.

So I created variables id1, id2, id3, brand1, brand2, brand3, size1, size2, size3, color1, color2, color3.

I want to put all these data into a table (`save_pdf_data`) with columns `id, brand, size` and `color`.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What have u tried? perhaps show us some code u have tried?

Comment: you have to show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO save_pdf_data (id, brand, size, color) 
VALUES ('id1', 'brand1', 'size1', 'color1'), 
       ('id2', 'brand2', 'size2', 'color2'), 
       ('id3', 'brand3', 'size3', 'color3')
```

You can grab all your data and feed in using a loop. Something as shown below in PHP:

```
$data = [['id1', 'brand1', 'size1', 'color1'], ['id2', 'brand2', 'size2', 'color2'], ['id3', 'brand3', 'size3', 'color3']];
$appender = "";
foreach ($data as $key) {
    $appender .= "('" . $key[0] . "', '" . $key[1] . "', '" . $key[2] . "'), ";
}

$appender = substr($appender, 0, -2);

$sql = "INSERT INTO save_pdf_data (id, brand, size, color) VALUES " . $appender;
print_r($sql);
```

`

Hope this answers your question

Comment: You need to get rid of the single quotes in the `VALUES()` portion - otherwise, you're inserting **literal string values** (like `brand3`) instead of the **value** of the `brand3` variable ...

Comment: Of course, this is assuming the literal values and not the variable since no specific language for pushing the data was stated. Good call.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO save_pdf_data (id, brand, size, color) VALUES ('id1','brand1','size1','color1');
INSERT INTO save_pdf_data (id, brand, size, color) VALUES ('id2','brand2','size2','color2');
```